# Santander scrip dividend shares - how to calculate base cost for UK capital gains tax

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, shares

I own various Spanish shares and often receive scrip or stock dividends in lieu of cash.  When I come to sell how do I work out the base cost of the shares for UK capital gains tax purposes? I know it is not the cash equivalent of the dividend, which would be the case for UK shares. Many thanks.